# Salesforce Chatter

Tags: chatter, partner-portal

Can I use chatter to collaborate partners that are managing opportunity within a separate salesforce org?

Also, please explain a scenario if you have come across one.

Comment: can you please specify the scenario...

Answer (score 1):

**Short:**

You are not able to connect salesforce orgs via chatter.

**BUT**

In case your SFDC org has a partner community you can create community users for your partners to manage opportunities with them together.

Answer (score 0):

Chatter is not multi-org.  Two possible solutions:

- Build or buy a cross-org chatter solution.  This essentially duplicates the chatter across orgs in a way which is transparent to the user.  MakePositive is a partner which has developed a solution to do this.
- Implement Partner Community and ask your partners to log into your org to drive that collaboration.

The MakePositive solution is technically sound but really only practicable for a small number or orgs.

DISCLAIMER - I work at Salesforce and in a previous role ran Sales Engineering for Chatter.  All opinions my own etc...